# Replace category name with article id in wordpress urls

Tags: urls

I would like to know, using wordpress, how to replace the category name with the article id in the url ? For example, I have a url of this kind :

```
http://mywebsite.com/css/the-name-of-my-css-article
```

And I would like to change it into :

```
http://mywebsite.com/article-id/the-name-of-my-css-article
```

Is there anybody who know to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try turning on [Pretty Permalinks](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks) and setting it to `%post_id%/%postname%`.